# Lambda Function to Compare 2 Lists With Multiple Criteria

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a lambda function that I need to use to compare 2 lists and return those records from one list that are in the second list. The lambda function has 4 comparisons. The first three search within the original list, while the 4th is the part that does the comparison.

```
IEnumerable<IssueDataModel> keywordissues = _adoSqlService.Search_Keyword(searchText);
IEnumerable<IssueDataModel> returnedIssues = issueList;
returnedIssues = issueList.Where(s => s.issueId.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()) ||
    s.issueTitle.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()) ||
    s.issueDescription.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()) ||
    s.issueId.Intersect(keywordissues.Select(y => y.issueId)) 
);
return returnedIssues;
```

The problem I'm having is the part were I do the "intersect". I'm getting the following error:

***string does not contain a definition for 'Intersect' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Intersect<string>' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>'***

How can I perform this short of doing this on the SQL side?

Comment: `s.issueId.Intersect()` assumes you want to intersect two `IEnumerable<char>`. The left-hand side (`s.issueId`) is a `string` which implicitly also is an `IEnumerable<char>`. The right-hand side is an `IEnumerable<string>`, though. I guess, the error you are seeing comes from this mismatch.

Comment: `Intersect()` does not return a `bool` anyway so you probably want to do this: `keywordissues.Select(y => y.issueId).Contains(s.issueId)`. But be aware that this is not very performant.